# How can I read the input value dynamically generated by the Query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how can i read dynamic created  value?

```
$('#inputArea').append("
      <input id = "arrivalTime1" type = 'number' placeholder='Arrival Time' style = 'display: none;'>
      ");
```

and I wanted reading ID arrivalTime1 value so try it

```
console.log(document.getElementById("#arrivalTime1"));
```

and try it.. but fail

```
    console.log('#arrivalTime1');
```

but can not reading..

plz help me

Comment: The first block of code will create an error.

Comment: Assuming that that is just a typo, you can `console.log($('#arrivalTime1'));`

Comment: Remove the pound symbol from your document.getElementById

Comment: You could put a `onValueChange` event listener on the input element.

Comment: Use `document.getElementById('arrivalTime1').value` to retrieve value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is:

```
document.getElementById('arrivalTime1').value
```